# Django settings based on IP or hostname

Tags: python, django, settings, ip, hostname

I'd like to have something in my settings like

```
if ip in DEV_IPS:
   SOMESETTING = 'foo'
else:
   SOMESETTING = 'bar'
```

Is there an easy way to get the ip or hostname - also - is this is a bad idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

However, I'd recommend against this and instead maintain multiple settings file for each environment you're working with.

```
settings/__init__.py
settings/qa.py 
settings/production.py
```

`__init__.py` has all of your defaults.  At the top of `qa.py`, and any other settings file, the first line has:

```
from settings import *
```

followed by any overrides needed for that particular environment.

Comment: Damn, was just about to post this answer. :( And I agree that using multiple settings file is probably a better idea.

Comment: you can use "export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.qa" in bash to pick which settings file to use

Comment: OK, thinking about it having multiple settings has got to be a better idea, *but* this answers the (misguided?) question I asked so this one will get the tick.

Answer (score 3):

One method some shops use is to have an environment variable set on each machine. Maybe called "environment". In POSIX systems you can do something like `ENVIRONMENT=production` in the user's .profile file (this will be slightly different for each shell and OS). Then in `settings.py` you can do something like this:

```
import os

if os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'production':
    # Production
    DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
    DATABASE_NAME = ....
else:
    # Development
```